# check response from server in android

Tags: android, json, request, response

Here i am passing Json object to server ,after successful post how to get the response from server based on following code ,[followed](http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/) this to get httpresponse but both are different ,how to do it .suggest something ,Thank you

```
public static String POST(String url, Person person) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("name", person.getName());
        jsonObject.accumulate("country", person.getCountry());
        jsonObject.accumulate("twitter", person.getTwitter());

        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();

        // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string using
        // Jackson Lib
        // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the
        // content
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        String httpresultss = EntityUtils
                .toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        System.out.println(httpresultss);
        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if (inputStream != null) {
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

        } else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    // 11. return result
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check like this way.

```
if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

   // do your stuff here

}
```

Further you can go with this http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html

You can also use ***getResponseMessage()***, it will a string message.

Comment: i want to display the status

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/x-andbene1/index.html?ca=drs-) might b useful to you for complete ins and out

Add Make sure this is in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Example ASAP Code for quick reference

```
StringBuilder response  = new StringBuilder();

    URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
    HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    if (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
    {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()),8192);
        String strLine = null;
        while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            response.append(strLine);
        }
        input.close();
    }
    return response.toString();
```